# Access Denied after changing the MS Project Server 2013 Permission Mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, project-server

I changed my MS Project Server 2013 Web App Permission from SharePoint Mode to Project Server mode

Now when I add users to any groups they can not access the web Ap.
and they see this message:

> Sorry, you don't have access to this page

I even added one of the users as site collection administrator but still he can not access.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Project Server permission mode beside granting permissions in SharePoint root site, you should give permissions to the users required for Project Server Access (for example, via assigning them into projects as resources, adding their Active Directory groups to Project Server groups, assigning their Project Server groups to Project Server categories, etc.). Project Server permission is a rather complex theme itself.

Further info to the theme:

[Video series: How security permissions work in Project Server](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Video-series-How-security-permissions-work-in-Project-Server-a19fb429-4f8f-4aa1-a186-8a33650c9801)

[Manage users, groups, and categories in Project Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197571.aspx)

[Plan groups, categories, and RBS in Project Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197354.aspx)

Regarding the SharePoint permissions, the user need (as far as I remember) at least Read permissions set on the following sites / libraries (each of this entities have their own permission set defined):

PWA

PWA/Project Detail Pages

PWA/Project Server Workflow History

PWA/Project Server Workflow Tasks

PWA/ProjectBICenter